# r lm parameter estimates

Tags: r, parameters, lm

**error variable length differs**

I am confused with this error and I don't know what to do.

```
n1<-20
m1<-0
sd1<-1
y<-rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
x<-rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
e<-rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
b0<-0
b1<-1

modelfit1<-lm(y~ b0 + b1*x + e)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ b0 + b1 * x + e:
variable lengths differ (found for 'b0')
```

edited: 
I am working on such case where n=20,  the parameters b0=0, and b=1 are true and the independent and the error are normally distributed with mean=0 and sd=1. 
Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you _want_ to do?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I think your simulated example does not really match what you want to do. Maybe this post would help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99924/simulate-regression-data-with-dependent-variable-being-non-normally-distributed

Comment: A comment on where the error comes from: R thinks that the model you want to fit contains a response variable y (so far so good), and a complicated combination of explanatory variables (one called b0, one called b1, one called x, one interaction term between the variables x and b1 and a final term that I don't even know how R will interpret it). If your intention was to generate a simple dataset to fit a simple linear model on (and I think it was your intention), then you need to fix your simulated data.

Comment: @coffeinjunky hello, i want to see the estimate standard error of the parameter b0 and b1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you put everything in a `data.frame` and deal with it that way:

```
set.seed(2)
m1<-0
sd1<-1
y<-rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
x<-rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
b0<-0
b1<-1

d <- data.frame(y,b0,b1,x,e=rnorm(20,0,1))
head(d)
#             y b0 b1            x          e
# 1 -0.89691455  0  1  2.090819205 -0.3835862
# 2  0.18484918  0  1 -1.199925820 -1.9591032
# 3  1.58784533  0  1  1.589638200 -0.8417051
# 4 -1.13037567  0  1  1.954651642  1.9035475
# 5 -0.08025176  0  1  0.004937777  0.6224939
# 6  0.13242028  0  1 -2.451706388  1.9909204
```

Now things work nicely:

```
modelfit1 <- lm(y~b0+b1*x+e, data=d)
modelfit1
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ b0 + b1 * x + e, data = d)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           b0           b1            x            e         b1:x  
#     0.19331           NA           NA     -0.06752      0.02240           NA  
summary(modelfit1)
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ b0 + b1 * x + e, data = d)
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.5006 -0.4786 -0.1425  0.6211  1.8488 
# Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.19331    0.25013   0.773    0.450
# b0                NA         NA      NA       NA
# b1                NA         NA      NA       NA
# x           -0.06752    0.21720  -0.311    0.760
# e            0.02240    0.20069   0.112    0.912
# b1:x              NA         NA      NA       NA
# Residual standard error: 1.115 on 17 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.006657,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1102 
# F-statistic: 0.05697 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.9448
```

Comment: thank you. though i am really confused how the parameters b0 and b1 have NA.

Comment: In this case, they are singular and invariant, so they can have no impact on the model. Realize that the model is already including an intercept (`(Intercept)`), which your formula is trying to mimick with `b0`; if you want to exclude the automatic intercept in the formula, you'll need to subtract one in the formula, as in `y ~ b0 + b1*x + e - 1`, which now gives you a meaningful `b1` but still `b0` is invariant ... which doesn't help your model. If this is for a class, I suggest you go ask the professor about what's happening here.

Comment: BTW: adding `b1` is also meaningless here, since the `x` line in the `summary` output is giving you what it thinks the coefficient of `x` *should be* given this model. If you really want to force it, then perhaps you should not be including `x` in the model.

Comment: In the long run, I'd think a more meaningful formula could be `y ~ x + e`.

Comment: Just a note: in addition, one could also use `I(b1*x)` in the model formula as it would then not be interpreted as an interaction term, but as the actual product of these two columns. Not clear though that this is what is the OPs intent.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but I believe you want to simulate an outcome and then estimate it's parameters. If that is true, you would rather do the following:

```
n1 <- 20
m1 <- 0
sd1<- 1
b0 <- 0
b1 <- 1

x <- rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
e <- rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)


y <- b0 + b1*x + e
summary(lm(y~x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.66052 -0.40203  0.05659  0.44115  1.38798 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.3078     0.1951  -1.578    0.132    
x             1.1774     0.2292   5.137  6.9e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.852 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5945,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.572 
F-statistic: 26.39 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 6.903e-05
```

And in case you want to do this multiple times, consider the following:

```
repetitions <- 5
betas <- t(sapply(1:repetitions, function(i){
  y <- b0 + b1*x + rnorm(n1,m1, sd1)
  coefficients(lm(y~x))
  }))
betas
     (Intercept)         x
[1,]  0.21989182 0.8185690
[2,] -0.12820726 0.7289041
[3,] -0.27596844 0.9794432
[4,]  0.06145306 1.0575050
[5,] -0.31429950 0.9984262
```

Now you can look at the mean of the estimated betas:

```
colMeans(betas)
(Intercept)           x 
-0.08742606  0.91656951
```

and the variance-covariance matrix:

```
var(betas)
             (Intercept)            x
(Intercept)  0.051323041 -0.007976803
x           -0.007976803  0.018834711
```